# codeigniter uri (URL) setup using router

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

i have codeigniter project. i am show the product page using router.php for the url change. Here i am facing some problems. the router code is here

```
Url                                 router.php code   
www.sitename.com/products/page/2 -> $route['products/page/(:num)'] = "products";
www.sitename.com/products/product-name -> $route['products/(:any)'] = "products/detail/$1";
www.sitename.com/products/product-categories -> $route['products/(:any)/(:num)'] = "products/selbygrp/$2";
```

the above code working fine for particular product detail view. But logically i have issues

problem:
 if i go to pagination links the router go to second route code . and also if select particular product group categories list it will go to second route code . what ever i gave it will go to second route line.

i know the reason for this. if products/ after anything it will take second route. but i don't need like this. the following urls i want

```
www.sitename.com/products/productname -> for product detailview
www.sitename.com/products/product-categories -> list product categories wise 
www.sitename.com/products/page/number -> show product list with pagenation
```

i am stuck with this, if any possible to do with htaccess for this, give me the guidance thanks advance

Comment: are you having issues with the pagination and routers? If so it would be helpful to see your pagination code

Comment: issues not with pagination. the issue is after products anything the url pass to second route that's issue, otherwise the pagination working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all of you gave me a good answer. finally i found the answer. the answer is here
when the url go to product categories , i created a controller for it and then i routed 
like this

```
url -> www.sitename.com/productgroup/groupname

route -> $route['productgroup/(:any)'] = "productgroup/selgrp/$1";
```

the above route is redirect to productgroup controller when i am hit the product categories. so the pagination problem also solved.

again i say thanks to every to gave me good answer.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, just move

```
$route['products/(:any)/(:num)'] = "products/selbygrp/$2";
```

above

```
$route['products/(:any)'] = "products/detail/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, your link breaks after the second page of the pagination. When it sticks this /2 or any other number in the url.

This is what I have to fix that issue, I was doing the same thing last night.

In my pagination base url I switched it to the new url

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url()."/products;
```

and then in my routes I added another route to accommodate for the pagination.

```
$route['products/(:any)'] = "products/page/$1";
```